# Push bypasses Gerrit Code Review (TortoiseGit)

Tags: git, gerrit

I need to be able to push to a repository but using the code-review feature. To push I am using tortoisegit for this, when pushing to master I get this error:

ssh://myusername@myorganization:29418/project
! [remote rejected] master -> master (can not update the reference as a fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to ssh://myusername@myorganization:29418/project

The only way I am able to push is by adding the Push permission to the group but this bypasses the code-review. How can I set up Gerrit so that it allows me to push for review?

I wasn't the person who set this up so I am having problems to understand the required permissions, I have read the ACL documentation of Gerrit but I don't have clear what I have to do.

[image: Our current permissions for this project]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your permissions are probably right, but you should push to refs/for/master instead of master. For example,

```
git push ssh://myusername@myorganization:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Answer (score 8):

And if you want to bypass the gerrit review and merge any change use *heads* instead of *for*. Command will be

```
git push ssh://myusername@myorganization:29418/project HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

Comment: +1. Please note that this requires the 'Push' permission to be set on the 'Reference:refs/heads/*' section of the gerrit access panel.