# Move git repository from Github to Gerrit automatically

Tags: git, gerrit, rebase

Need to push existing git repo to Gerrit however have issues doing this:

```
remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
```

because repo did not contain `.git/hooks/commit-msg`. Now I have the script installed, however need to change hundreds of commit messages to add `Change-Id` everywhere. How to make it automatically in the best and easiest way? 
Possible solutions:

1. I see some [topics here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8849682/630169) suggest to use `git rebase -i`, however it is interactive and mostly manual process.
2. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234236/630169) to use `sed` command with `git rebase` as commit message editor. What is the exact `rebase` command  will be in my case?
3. [Third proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25816638/630169) to use `git filter-branch` command, however it works only for commits on a current branch that have not yet been pushed to an upstream branch.

Any other solutions, fixes or suggestions for the above? Thanks!

Comment: It seems nonsensical that Gerrit would require retroactively addding Change-Ids to an existing Git repository. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789666/import-repository-from-git-to-gerrit

Comment: @Schwern, our Gerrit set up to prohibit direct pushing bypassing review, or I do not have access rights to do this: command `git push gerrit HEAD:master` produces error: `! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (prohibited by Gerrit)`

Comment: It seems you can bypass review by pushing to `HEAD:refs/heads/master`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215375/14660 and https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#bypass_review

Comment: @Schwern, no I can't: still ` ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (prohibited by Gerrit)`. As mentioned in comment for https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215375/630169: this requires the 'Push' permission to be set on the 'Reference:refs/heads/*' section of the gerrit access panel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do talk to the Gerrit administrators and ask for permission to push direct to branch bypassing review. Explain what you're trying to do telling that you just need this permission temporally (after the execution of the "git push gerrit HEAD:refs/heads/master" command the permission can be removed).

Other possibility: ask to the Gerrit administrators or someone who has permission to push to refs/heads/* (configuration managers use to have such permission) to execute the command for you.

Do NOT change retroactively the past commits, this isn't a good idea.

Comment: I do not have possibility for now to get this rights, so it is not the case. Need some solution for the 2nd point.